# How to add the border to a cell without miss-aligning everything?

Tags: css, html-table, jsfiddle

I'd like to have a right border on the bottom left cell (actually the left-most cell of the second table) without messing up the positioning of the cells on it's right...

https://jsfiddle.net/horacebury/vnng82qp/4/

The CSS is very fiddly...

```
.tg td{font-family:Times New Roman, sans-serif;font-size:16px;border-style:solid;border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px;border-spacing:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;background-color: #EEE;border-color: #DDD;border-top: none !important;text-align: right; vertical-align: top; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; }
.tg .tg-yw4l{ width: 145px; padding: 4px 4px 4px 0px; }
.tg .tg-yw4g{ width: 49px; padding: 4px 0px 4px 0px; border-width: 0px 0px 1px 1px; }
```

Comment: What does it mess up? I added a right border to bottom left cell with `7016.32` in it and nothing "messed up" as far as I could see?

Comment: The cell with the the-yw4g style is empty. You're talking about the one next to it.

Comment: Ah... Everything shifts right by 1 pixel. I would be inclined to say that is not noticeable, but I am sure you have your reasons.

Comment: I know what you mean, but when it lines up nicely it's so much better. I'm convinced this is possible, but it's beating me so far.

Comment: I know what it's like to not want css to get the better of you :-)

Comment: I suggest redoing your table since the HTML doesn't make sense. There is no reason why your first column should be in it's own `tbody`. Also, your last row could be using `tfoot` and not another `tbody`. The entire thing needs to be in one table. I would set borders for top and bottom on the rows itself, not the cells. Then I would add right borders to every cell. That would give you what you want.

Comment: Which table are you looking at? I haven't put a tbody on the second table.

Comment: Your last row, the "total" line has it's own table and `tbody`, when it could have just been a `tfoot` of the above table. Your HTML for such a simple table is overly complex, which makes the CSS harder to manage.

Comment: I'm not creating the above table - it is the HandsOnTable library, so I'm not at (easy) liberty to modify it.

Comment: Also, I'm not deliberately adding the tbody element.

Comment: Is the size of the table ever going to change? If not, you could just set the width on some of the cells to move it over.

Comment: That's in fact what I've done, it didn't work.

Comment: @MattW Did you see my second suggestion? It addresses this option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution using border or box-sizing. You can do it using a pseudoelement though.

**note** Because the cell next to it has `overflow: hidden`, the pseudoelement has to be positioned relative to the table, and not the cell.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/p2hwfwqx/1/)

```
.tg {
  position: relative;
}

.tg::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 26px;
  top: 0;
  left: 50px;
  background: red;
  width: 1px;
}
```

**update**

Another way to do this would be to target the affected cell to the right.

```
.tg .tg-yw4g {
  width: 49px;
  padding: 4px 0px 4px 0px;
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 1px;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}

.tg .tg-yw4g + td {
  width: 144px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/q2pbps0k/1/)